# Using git in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I am having trouble in using git on android studio. I know there may be many related questions asked on this topic But I could not find any relevant answer.

I can use git normally but with android studio i am facing many problems. I am working on a project with my friend. The main project is on his repository. I have forked his repo. And cloned the project on my machine. Then using imported the project on my  Android Studio. Till here things are fine but after this everything messes up when i try to use git.

Do i have to use git in the terminal inside android studio itself, or in normal terminal in file manager?

Can anyone give me a proper guide of how to collaborate on Android Studio using Git.

Comment: Please provide more details. Describe step by step what you did and what the result was. Did you get an error? If so, show it. Better yet, you should google that error message.

Comment: The problem is i need a complete guide on how to use git on Android Studio. Because i tried solving errors ,but that ultimately leads me to More and more errors.:-(

Comment: Sadly SO is not the place to ask for guides. Instead your best bet is to search online.

Comment: Android Studio is based on IntelliJ. So if you are unable to find documentation when searching "Android Studio <some feature>" try "IntelliJ <some feature>" instead.

Comment: In fact googling "Android Studio git" gives a lot of hits that can get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use git just as you wish... Git is a part of the project and hence does not depend on the Git client.
For example, I mostly use SourceTree as my main Git client.

But when I create a new repo, or push an existing project into a new repo, I prefer to use the command line.

Now when it comes to merging, I really appreciate the AndroidStudio merging tool, So I begin my merge with SourceTree and solve conflicts with Android Studio ^^

The best tool is the one you are comfortable with, however note that they are just front-end for the git (command-line) tool.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a Git project in Android Studio, detects by the itself that your project is a Git project.

You will be able to see in the bottom of Android Studio something like this:

[image]

You can commit using **Control + K**

If you can't see it, maybe your git configuration/project is wrong.